# Configuring Apache/PHP/mySQL on Windows .. almost done

Tags: php, apache, mysqli

I've followed the below guide to setup my local host

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/how-to-setup-local-web-server-with-latest-apache-php-and-mysql-packages/

I'd like to use PHP 5.3.10 to use the same version as my live site, although when I use the newer version and navigate to localhost/pma I get the following error:

```
The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. <a href="Documentation.html#faqmysql" target="documentation"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Documentation" alt="Documentation" class="icon ic_b_help" /></a>
```

Anyone know what else needs to be done to properly configure mySQLi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open you **php.ini** file and make sure the **extension=mysqli.so** (or **extension=mysqli.dll** on windows) isn't commented out.

Also make sure that you have the mysqli.so or mysqli.dll files inside the extensions folder of your php installation.

Comment: i have checked out these steps .. but it still doesn't work !! 
mysqli.dll in his correct position !!

Comment: I'm working on ubuntu12.04 with php5, i can't find mysqli.so in /etc/php5/apache2

Answer (score 1):

Yea check your "Services" first and make sure MySQL is running proper.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your firewall settings and create inbound/outbound rules for MySQL.exe

Answer (score -1):

As I recall, it's because the mySQL service is not installed or running properly